# Need XPath and XQuery query

Tags: xpath, xquery

I'm working on Xpath/Xquery to return values of multiple child nodes based on a sibling node value in a single query. My XML looks like this

```
<FilterResults>
        <FilterResult>
            <ID>535</ID>
            <Analysis>
                <Name>ZZZZ</Name>
                <Identifier>asdfg</Identifier>
                <Result>High</Result>
                <Score>0</Score>
            </Analysis>
            <Analysis>
                <Name>XXXX</Name>
                <Identifier>qwerty</Identifier>
                <Result>Medium</Result>
                <Score>0</Score>
            </Analysis>
        </FilterResult>
        <FilterResult>
            <ID>745</ID>
            <Analysis>
                <Name>XXXX</Name>
                <Identifier>xyz</Identifier>
                <Result>Critical</Result>
                <Score>0</Score>
            </Analysis>
            <Analysis>
                <Name>YYYY</Name>
                <Identifier>qwerty</Identifier>
                <Result>Medium</Result>
                <Score>0</Score>
            </Analysis>
        </FilterResult>
</FilterResults>
```

I need to get values of **Score** and **Identifier** based on **Name** value. I'm currently trying with below query but not working as desired

```
fn:string-join((
  for $Identifier in fn:distinct-values(FilterResults/FilterResult/Analysis[Name="XXXX"]) 
  return fn:string-join((//Identifier,//Score),'-')),',')
```

The output i'm looking for is this

`qwerty-0,xyz-0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question suggests some fundamental misunderstandings about XQuery, generally. It's hard to explain everything in a single answer, but 1) that is not how `distinct-values` works (it returns string values, not nodes), and 2) the double slash selections in your return statement are returning everything because they are not constrained by anything. The XPath you use inside the `distinct-values` call is very close, however.

Instead of calling `distinct-values`, you can assign the `Analysis` results of that XPath to a variable, iterate over them, and generate concatenated strings. Then use `string-join` to comma separate the full sequence. Note that in the return statement, the variable `$a` is used to `concat` only one pair of values at a time.

```
string-join(
  let $analyses := FilterResults/FilterResult/Analysis[Name="XXXX"]
  for $a in $analyses
  return $a/concat(Identifier, '-', Score),
  ',')
```

=> `qwerty-0,xyz-0`